# Find the complete function definition inside C++ shared object file

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, linker-errors

I have a linker error where it says undefined reference to a function. The shared library where I expect the function to be has that function name ( I checked through nm -s ) so now the next thing I want to see is if the function parameters are correct. How do I see the type and number of parameters for a function in a shared object file ?

EDIT: So the problem it came to be was: I was trying to create a C++ shared object file by linking a shared *C* object, but in the C++ source I did not include the header inside "extern "C" " block, so it was not able to find those symbols, Thanks to all who replied to this question. This question is resolved now.

Comment: What is the "nm" tag on this question?

Comment: @JohnDibling: `nm` is a command in unix/Linux systems which gives you a list of symbols in an object file.

Comment: Ah.  Might be better to tag this question [linux] rather than [nm]

Comment: Normally C++ function names are mangled, so the symbol you see with nm will be mangled too, and by that already contains the parameters in question. You could show a bit more information, like program outputs. Also, did you check that the nm output doesn't show the symbol as an unresolved one?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Yes I redirected the nm output to c++filt program to demangle, it only shows the function name, I double checked again now, but it shows T symbol in front of it.

Comment: @JohnDibling I think it is POSIX, not limited to Linux.

Comment: Is the function name actually mangled ? C++ will mangle the function names, however C does not (there is no overload).

Comment: I am linking a C++ object to a shared C object file, so yeah, its not mangled, but anyways, I pass --demangle option

Answer (score 10):

You can use `nm` with the `--demangle` option:

```
nm -s --demangle libWhatever.so
```

trying that out on a sample .so gives me output such as

> 00005820 T detail::print_(std::ostream&, cv::Mat const&, std::string const&)

`T` just means that it is in the object files used to make the `.so` and does not need to be resolved by the linker.

Comment: The capital `T` means that the symbol is defined and has external linkage. Such a symbol defined in a `.so` is always resolved by the dynamic linker at run-time and thus can be superimposed.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
nm --demangle --defined-only --dynamic x.so
```

The above demangles C++ names and shows only defined symbols in the dynamic section, which is defined symbols with external linkage one can link against.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing c++filt on the mangled name. It will unmangle it and you can see the arguments.

Comment: Yes I redirected the nm output already to c++filt program to demangle, it only shows the function name, I double checked again now. Also it shows T symbol in front of it, I am not sure what does that mean.

Comment: Ok I read, T means the object file contains the definition but why its not showing the parameters

Comment: Can you post what you get above? This may help.. :)

Comment: this is the output that I get:                                        nm -s --demangle  libRobotConnection.so.0.0.0  |  grep connection_set     00a8d990 T robot_connection_set

Answer (score 0):

So the problem it came to be was: I was trying to create a C++ shared object file by linking a shared *C* object, but in the C++ source I did not include the header inside "extern "C" " block, so it was not able to find those symbols, Thanks to all who replied to this question. This question is resolved now.