# Linking issues with C++ ABI changes introduced in C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, abi

I have a static library and its corresponding headers. It was built in our build-system and one of the functions it provides has a signature like this

```
// said_header.h
#ifndef ...
#define ...

namespace some_namespace
{
void foo(std::string const&)
}

#endif // ...
```

I have also a cpp-file that includes said header and calls this function

```
// test.cpp
#include <said_header.h>

int main()
{
    some_namespace::foo("This is a test");
}
```

When I try to compile this example I get an error that says the following

```
> g++ test.cpp -o ./build/example -I./libname/include -L./libname/lib -lname
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoXNloc.o: in function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `some_namespace::foo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

Alright, so I look for the corresponding object-file and use `nm` to obtain the mangled name and use `c++filt` to check to what this corresponds

```
> nm path/to/object_file.o | grep 'some_fancy_regex'
_ZN6some_namespace12fooERKSs
> c++filt _ZN6some_namespace12fooERKSs
some_namespace::foo(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

and indeed, this does not correspond to what I called the function... The difference seems to be between `std::basic_string` and `std::__cxx11::basic_string`. So, as a quick experiment I added `#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0` to `test.cpp` before the include of `said_header.h` and everything compiled fine.

My suspicion was that I was using different gcc version, compile flags, etc. so I started trying to chase this down... The build system uses CentOS 7 with `gcc-11.2.1` while my machine uses Ubuntu 22.04  with `gcc-11.4.0`. Since the versions were not the same, I also tried to compile the example with `gcc-11.2.1`, but this did not fix the issue either..
Other than that, all flags are identical (I used `-frecord-gcc-switches` to check what compile flags were used when building the static lib and made sure to use the same when compiling the example (`-mavx -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -O3 -std=gnu++20 -fopenmp -fPIC`)) but it still doesn't work..

I have no ideas anymore... Does anybody have any suggestions on how to approach this?

### Useful SO questions I consulted along the way:

- [Converting std::__cxx11::string to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394934/converting-std-cxx11string-to-stdstring)
- [Find the complete function definition inside C++ shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500591/find-the-complete-function-definition-inside-c-shared-object-file)

Comment: You already have your answer: Compile everything outside the CentOS system with `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` set to `0`. The setting needs to be consistent between different compilations that are linked together (more or less) and it is forced to `0` on CentOS 7. Also see [(How) Can I use the new C++ 11 ABI with devtoolset-7 on Centos/RHEL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393888/how-can-i-use-the-new-c-11-abi-with-devtoolset-7-on-centos-rhel), https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1546704

Comment: @user17732522 This was the missing piece, thank you! I didn't know that this was enforced on CentOS 7...